# How can I display multiple lines of version.php?

Tags: php, wordpress, version

I'm new to PHP code and am trying to find a way to display 3 lines from the `version.php` file within WordPress without having to download the file; look into it and move on - this is what I have come up with so far, but does not seem to be working. I'm sure I'm doing something wrong here and would greatly appreciate some help.

```
<?php
$version = "wp-includes/version.php";
$all_lines = file($version);
echo $all_lines[16];
echo $all_lines[23];
echo $all_lines[37];
?>
```

Comment: How is it not working? What are you expecting? What are you actually getting? Please see [**How do I ask a good question?**](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [**What topics can I ask about here?**](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)

Comment: While you need specified lines that's the correct way. What's your problem?

Comment: keep getting not found error when attempting to lod it as a .php file the version.php file i am trying to call the specific lines from would be under the file path of public/wp-inculdes/version.php  the code above is located at document root not super sure on what exactly is going wrong in it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To be able to see specific version numbers on your frontend its best to create a shortcode and use that shortcode to output.

Add the below code in `functions.php` file.

```php
function bks_show_versions( $atts ) {
    global $wpdb;
    $wordpress = $GLOBALS['wp_version'];
    $php_version = phpversion();
    $mysql_version = $wpdb->db_server_info();
    return sprintf("<pre> wordpress version : %s | php version: %s | mysql version : %s  </pre>", $wordpress, $php_version, $mysql_version);
}
add_shortcode( 'show_versions', 'bks_show_versions' );
```

This basically will fetch all the values and print them on the screen.
`<pre> wordpress version : 5.7 | php version: 7.4.16 | mysql version : 5.7.24  </pre>`

---

Now, at whichever page you want it to print,edit that page and add `[show_versions]` on that page. Now view that page. You should be able to see.

1. WordPress Version
2. PHP Version
3. MySql Version

You can use [this article](https://www.wpbeginner.com/wp-tutorials/how-to-add-a-shortcode-in-wordpress/) to understand how to add shortcode to a page.
The shortcode you have to add is : `[show_versions]`

Comment: - thankyou so much but how would i be able to implement this? , just by adding it to an index file or is there a specific way that arrays are to be added to the file structure ?

Comment: You can put the code inside your themes  `functions.php` file. Make sure to define `$version`.

Comment: <?php
$version = "version.php";
$all_lines = file($version);

$show_lines = [16, 23, 37]; // Add other line nos. you want to output.

foreach( $all_lines as $key => $item ) { // Loop 
   if ( in_array( $key, $all_lines ) ) { // check if key exist in line
    echo $item;  // echo
   }

that is now in the functions.php file how do i get it to display the lines being requested both version.php and functions.php are showing blank page

Comment: where do you want to display them ?? You cannot directly access `functions.php` and `version.php`.

Comment: really anywhere the main goal is to have a quick way to see the WP , php and DB versions by uploading a file and having it call the information   by going to domain.com/ phpversion or something similar

Comment: Hey @hazenBaisley, I have updated my code which will enable you to add shortcode on the page and see version numbers. Please read my answer again.

Comment: @hazen, please read this. https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers#:~:text=Choose%20one%20answer%20that%20you,the%20answer%2C%20at%20any%20time.